# Is my baby short for her age?

Tags: toddler, health, development

My baby girl is 13 months old.

At birth, her weight was 2.7 kg and her height was 55 cm.

Now at 13 months, her weight is 7.8 kg (tripled) and her height is only 71 cm. (less than doubled).

I'm worried about her height. Is it normal or should I consult a doctor?

Comment: Was your child premature? 3 weeks or more early? Those seem like small numbers. Our son was 3 weeks early and has put on more weight and grown more than our daughter who was full term

Comment: There are significant differences in what is considered "normal" depending on the genetic background. "Normal" for southeast asia can appear to be dangerously underweight for northern europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.babycenter.in/a1052197/baby-girls-growth-chart) average height for 13 months old girl is 75.2 cm and average weight is 9.2 kg. So your baby's height seems pretty normal. However, at this age the growth trend is important. Your pediatrician should have a record of height/weight at different ages and compare it to what is considered to be normal.

Answer (score 3):

It's not how tall she grows, but how steadily she grows.

[image]

This is a growth chart for an infant girl from birth to 36 months. The chart is based on the growth patterns of thousands of babies to determine what is "normal".

At 55 cm at birth, that would place her above the 95th %ile.
At 71 cm at 13 months, that would place her just at the 10th %ile.

That means she had "dropped" more than three percentile groups or "crossed" more than three percentile lines. That is considered by most physicians to indicate a problem.

With the newer WHO growth charts [available here](http://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/who_charts.htm#The%20WHO%20Growth%20Charts), the same phenomenon occurs.

(You can see that her weight is a different matter.)

You should definitely discuss this with your doctor.